# Build Jar File with multiple classes

Tags: java, jar

Is there a way to build a jar file that is anything inside a specific folder?

Inside my folder I have my main class named "GamesCombined.java" with it's .class files

Here's what my directory looks like inside GamesCombined folder

```
-> GamesCombined.java
-> GamesCombined.class //classes*
-> games (folder)
|
|----> pacman (folder)
|   |
|   |----> PacmanGame.java
|   |----> PacmanGame.class //classes*
|
|----> racinggame(folder)
     |
     |----> RacingGame.java
     |----> RacingGame.class //classes*
-> images (folder)
|
|----> pacman (folder)
|    |
|    |----> //jpg's and png's
|
|----> racinggame (folder)
     |
     |----> //jpg's and png's
```

I already made a jar file of the GamesCombined.java by following this link:
http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

But then it has an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: games/pacman/PacmanGame (wrong name: PacmanGame)

GamesCombined.java has import games.pacman.*;

Is there a way where I could just build a jar file including the other classes? What should I do? :o

I'm new when it comes on JAR files. :/

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Problem is with your manifest file, Can you paste it here.

Comment: Do you build the JAR using an IDE command ? Or from the command-line ? If you're doing it from the command-line, what is the command ?

Comment: @TimHerold - JCreator Pro

Comment: @loki Main-Class: GamesCombined

Comment: @JuvarAbrera: Is this the only entry in Manifest? What about classpath?

Comment: @RaduMurzea I build the jar file using cmd. Go to the link I mentioned above. Under 'Creating a jar File in Command Prompt', the first two commands under step #5

Comment: @loki I really don't know what you're talking about? Should I add something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the included Jar Builder of your IDE.
Java brings a tool which also can create JarFiles, take a look : [Creating a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

```
(your jdk/bin)jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

In both ways you have to check your classpath, written in your Manifest

**EDIT:**

JCreator Pro is quite easy:

click: 
Configure>Options>Tools>New>Create JAR File

this creates an user tool to create a JAR file, this does not yet include the manifest, you will have to manually add the manifest.

OR you can configure the command line switches to incorporate the manifest, try this for example:
cvmf $[PrjDir]\MANIFEST.MF $[PrjName].jar .

this should include the manifest 'MANIFEST.MF' in your project directory as a manifest. You will have to create that yourself though.

NOTE: this has *NOT* been tested

Comment: According to my problem, is this correct?
jar cfv GamesCombined.jar GamesCombined.class GamesCombined$1.class GamesCombined$2.class GamesCombined$3.class GamesCombined$4.class GamesCombined$5.class images games

Comment: Try to use the included JCreator function: [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5fF3oldcrQ)

Comment: I saw a tutorial on youtube. You open it with WinRar and goto Meta folder and I just put "Main-Class: GamesCombined" to manifest.mf. That right?

Comment: if you want to use the commandline try this `jar cvfm yourJarName.jar yourManifest -C yourMainFolder/`

Comment: @JuvarAbrera #ut "Main-Class: GamesCombined" to manifest.mf. That right?# Yes, but you also need to check your Classpath, here is an manifest entry example  `Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name`

Comment: Do I have to create a jar file for every class inside a sub folder? Edit: Nevermind. It's now working without that Class-Path: THANKS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35213/discussion-between-tim-herold-and-juvar-abrera)

Answer (score 0):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that you have not specified the package inside PacManGame.java (or you didn't recompile it before adding it to the jar).

```
package games.pacman;
public class PacManGame {
    ...
```

To answer the original question, you can create the jar file using

```
jar cvfm gamescombined.jar MANIFEST.MF -C GamesCombined/ .
```